# Calculus on Manifolds font

Tags: fonts

What is the font used in *Calculus on Manifolds* (Spivak)? This question has already been asked, but not answered. Also, where can I get it (including summation symbols, parentheses, etc.)?

Comment: You should tell us rather, where this book/volume is available in order to have a look ;-)

Comment: If the question has already been asked (but not answered), then this is a duplicate. Either way, this is an FAQ that is covered by [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://goo.gl/YsWvA)

Comment: although the cited practex article by spivak refers to baskerville, this sample doesn't look much like baskerville to me.  the giveaway is in the word/phrase "**angle preserving**" in the first paragraph.  compare the width of that word "angle" with the width of the lightface "angle" in item (b).  that's the hallmark of computer modern "bx".  the use of old-style digits is somewhat idiosyncratic, and the glyphs for relations aren't computer modern, but the text sure looks like it is.  i suspect this is not the edition referred to in spivak's article.